# Where to mail an IRS CP11 notice response?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

I received a CP11 notice regarding my Year 2020 tax return and would like to submit a response expressing my disagreement with the assessment. Despite the notice stating I should call to review my account with a representative, I am unable to reach anyone at the IRS (it seems like a cruel joke to suggest calling when it's nearly impossible to reach a real person).

I also can't locate an address to mail my response. I'm afraid the address on the payment stub is only for payments, and I don't want my response to get lost in the shuffle.

Where should one mail a letter for this type of correspondence?

Comment: How many times have you tried to call them?  If more than a few times, maybe call your Congressman and ask for help contacting them.

Comment: Doesn't the CP11 notice have an address on the letter? It may not look like an address/PO Box but just a ZIP+4 but that would be a valid place for mail delivery. Also see: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/understanding-your-cp11-notice

Comment: @MorrisonChang The notice came with a payment stub, but I am not sure if I should send it there. The address on the payment stub is the same on the letterhead.

Comment: IRS hasn't used letterhead for notices for decades. The _address block_ is printed as part of each notice and is specifically designed for the function that generated that particular notice, so yes it is the correct address.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I didn't know what else to call it except for "letterhead". Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

From IRS.gov,

> What should I do if I disagree with the changes you made?

> If you disagree, contact us at the toll-free number show at the top
> right corner of your notice, or **respond by mail to the address on your**
> **notice. If you write to us, include a copy of the notice along with**
> **your correspondence or documentation.** (emphasis added)
>
> We’ll reverse most changes we made if we increased the amount you owe
> or if your return requested a refund. However, you must contact us
> within 60 days from the date of your notice to request the reversal. ...

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/understanding-your-cp11-notice

Comment: Ignores the text of the question: "Despite the notice stating I should call to review my account with a representative, I am unable to reach anyone at the IRS (it seems like a cruel joke to suggest calling when it's nearly impossible to reach a real person)."

Comment: I added emphasis related to the original question.

Comment: "I'm afraid the address on the payment stub is only for payments, and I don't want my response to get lost in the shuffle."